# Position between two (lat,long)-coordinates in Python

Tags: python

I need to do the following in Python. Given two positios (lat1,lon1) and (lat2,lon2), I need to get the point (lat0,lon0) which lies on the path between the given two points at fraction alpha. I.e. alpha = 0.5 is the midpoint between the points, but I need to compute it for any 0 <=alpha <= 1. I would like to use a package already defined if possible, e.g. I use geopy.distance to compute distances between points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here there is a nice library:
[great-circle-calculator](https://pypi.org/project/great-circle-calculator/#intermediate_point)

The function you may look for is:

```
intermediate_point(p1, p2, fraction=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "Intermediate Point" section on [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) page.

It describes the formula mathematically:

> a = sin((1−f)⋅δ) / sin δ
>   b = sin(f⋅δ) / sin δ
>   x = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ cos λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos λ2
>   y = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ sin λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin λ2
>   z = a ⋅ sin φ1 + b ⋅ sin φ2
>   φi = atan2(z, √x² + y²)
>   λi = atan2(y, x)

Which translates into Python quite easily, and is translated into JavaScript on the page.

I was unable to find a way to do this using GeoPy.

Answer (score -1):

```
def find_point(a,b,alpha = 0.5):
    assert(0<=alpha<=1)
    new_a = ((1-alpha) * a[0], (1-alpha)*a[1])
    new_b = ((alpha) * b[0], alpha*b[1])
    return ((new_a[0]+new_b[0]), (new_a[1]+new_b[1]))
```

test-

```
>>>find_point((1,1),(2,2))
(1.5, 1.5)
```

Comment: This will not work for points closer to the longitudinal maximum/minimum than the center point.

Comment: Hi, the formula above assumes that the point lies on a straight line. I don't think this is the case for shortest distance when it comes to lat/lon coordinates